# Storing JSON object in cookies (Using JQuery) and reading and deserialize the same in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies, jquery-cookie

Im trying to store JSON object in cookies and for that Im using JQUERY Cookies library. So here is my code for setting up the cookies.

```
var batchParam={userid:10,username:"alex",batchid:20};
//So what I did is stringified the object and write it into cookies
Cookies.set("batchparam",JSON.stringify(batchParam);
```

In server side I created the class for deserialize the above structure

```
Public Class batchParam
    Public userid, batchid As Integer
    Public  username As String
End Class
```

In page load I was trying to deserialize using the following code.

```
Dim bpCookie As HttpCookie
Dim bp As New batchParam
bpCookie = Request.Cookies("batchParam")
Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer
bp = js.Deserialize(Of batchParam)(bpCookie.Value.ToString)
```

But its not showing as a proper string or JSON string so I cant deserialize.

**Here is the error message**[image]

So how can I deserialize the cookie string properly. It looks like string got encoded when storing into cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I got the solution. Sharing with those having the same trouble

first I removed the stringify when setting cookie. So it doesnt need to stringify and its writing JSON object directly.

> Cookies.set("batchparam",batchParam);

Then url decode in server side

> js.Deserialize(Of batchParam)(server.urldecode(bpCookie.Value))

It solved the problem and it perfectly deserialized the JSON from cookie

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL decode your cookie value:

```
bp = js.Deserialize(Of batchParam)(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(bpCookie.Value.ToString, Encoding.UTF8))
```